# Application for viewing coldfusion logs

Tags: coldfusion, logging

Straighforward question really

Wondering if there was an application specific for handling coldfusion log files.

At the moment I am opening them in notepad to view the details, but wondered if there was another solution

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything with a tail view will work.

CFBuilder has a built in log view that works well, although the product is still in Beta.  Tips on use ( http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/11/25/Quick-TailView-Tip )

The "Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools" also has a command line tail viewer that is less cumbersome. Search for that string to get the MS Download page for it.

Comment: Great thanks, I use cfbuilder already and was unaware of tail view...the link you provided is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using CFBuilder, but found a nice way of doing around this.

There's a nice eclipse plugin called "**[eclipsetail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsetail/)**" that does exactly that, and it doesn't rely on you having cfbuilder installed.

I've been using it for a long time, and it's really good, and does exactly the same as the version from cfbuilder.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response, i predominantly use cfbuilder, but will install this plugin for later use with cfeclipse.